# How to deal with “menstruation” during the post apocalypse?

Tags: post-apocalypse, medicine

So, there is a post apocalypse, a nuclear one, that destroys most modern day infrastructure, along with factories that produce, ummm, “female hygiene products”. The technology of the world has gone back to late-17th century levels, so my question is what could woman do about it during the apocalypse?

Comment: A basic web search will find you plenty of articles and references to e.g. menstruation in the middle ages.  Please do basic research before coming to WB.

Comment: This question is exactly, "What did women do about menstruation in the late-17th century." That is a history questions, so it is off-topic here. I am voting to close.

Comment: @StephenG: Hell no. That’s gross

Comment: Well if you think a world set back to the 17th century is gross for menstruation, you might want to give a bit of thought to such trivia as general health care (including childbirth !) and getting clean water.  You loose a lot of infrastructure and capability to make things when you dash back to the 17th century.  Knowledge of how to does not equate to ability to manufacture.

Comment: If this is not a simple history question, you should make it clear how it differs.

Comment: @Mark Olson: most people live nomadic lifestyles

Comment: Women managed to live very well without ultra-modern feminine hygiene products for thousands of years. In most countries in this world women used traditional methods to deal with this monthly problem up to the second half of the 20th century, which is to say, there are very many women in this world who know what to do, from their mothers or grandmothers. It's not as if modern tampons have existed for centuries and knowledge about life before tampons has been lost in the mists of time or is confined to the deepest recesses of secret libraries.

Comment: This could be perfectly on-topic, but you could've done a simple google search and then included your own research. I don't think it's bad to not trust the results and double-check by asking, but at least show some effort. It is recommended to downvotes questions (see https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5914/what-to-do-about-trivial-questions ) that have issues such as yours. Perhaps this should be communicated better, but if you are wondering why you have 3 downvotes so far ...

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure I'd say that "women managed to live very well ..." in this context.  "Made the best of a bad lot" might be a better choice of words.  Put another way, would you prefer to have been born a man or a a woman in the 17th century ?

Comment: Are you aware that nomadic life style is common for thousand years and that also for nomad women pads were not invented earlier than last century, yet they managed to live their life?

Comment: The Bible’s description of how to handle menstration doesn’t make it sound pleasant or well handled. And a couple older women I have interviewed about how it went were more than a bit ecstatic about the tampon invention. Still, basic web search will answer this question with fair amount of detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apocalypse doesn't mean cloth has suddenly disappeared. Maybe I'm being a chauvinistic male pig, but why would women suddenly forget how to fold up a piece of cloth and stick it down there until the bleeding stops? Maybe not as comfy and sanitary as factory made pads and tampons, but its not like people are so stupid they would forget how to take care of basic bodily functions once their Iphones and wifi quite working.

Comment: Perhaps men should just not include a lot of details about menstruation into their fictional works in general. I'm not saying my comment and your answer are a perfect fit, but since it's the accepted answer and tries to solve this with common sense (got my upvote), I'm gonna present what I would call common sense.

Comment: I'm not trying to be too mean, but after a certain point exposition is just not needed in a story. If it isn't furthering the plot then it probably shouldn't be included. Personally when a person thinks I as a reader am too dumb to figure out how people go to the bathroom or wash themselves then I begin to feel like my intelligence is being insulted. As a writer building a world always think of the audience.

Comment: Also, don't feel like you cant write from a female perspective. Stephen King's breakout smash hit Carrie was pretty much one giant metaphor about PMS and menstruation. Its just that you cant come out the gate and beat your audience to death with unnecessary direct exposition. Show don't tell, maybe a girl's mom has to teach her how to make her own sanitary products and explain the birds and the bees to her, this provides a detail of how primitive life has become without simply punching me in the face with a 3 page clinical description of sanitary practices.

Comment: I'm often careful with my words. Often I'm not, but I was in this case. I used "in general. " because I don't think there are no circumstances, but in general you should really think twice, especially if you have to ask on the internet. Btw assuming "Logan" is male, it's a male name.

Comment: The first line is mildly offensive (or can be read as such) so could you please replace "Mentally Disabled" with "Stupid" ?

Comment: Its supposed to be mildly offensive in order to illustrate the mildly offensive preconceptions the author has towards his subject and the audience, which was evidently successful. If the semantics of the phrasing bother you I apologize, but will not change it.

Comment: The people you are offending will be those with relatives unfortunate enough to be stricken with mental disabilities through no fault of their own.  Please find another way to insult the OP ( if you feel you must do that ).

Comment: @StephenG amusing. The training for a place I worked recently was to never use “stupid” for anything and always use “mentally disabled” instead... for exactly the reason you cite.

Comment: @SRM The problem here is that "mentally disabled " is being *used* as an insult.  The problem you are talking about is when "stupid" is being used to refer to people with mental disabilities - which is the opposite context.

Comment: @StephenG No, actually, it was all contexts. I referred to a computer as stupid insofar as it would do exactly what you tell it to do even if that's a bad idea, and I was told to refer to it as mentally disabled.

Comment: don't forget the "be nice"